# How do I programmitcally launch EXE by disabling compatibility mode?

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess, shellexecute, shellexecuteex

User launches my EXE runs in compatibility mode which launches another EXE but I don't want the child EXE to inherit the compatibility mode settings. How do I achieve it? Cannot find any resources which makes this work.

I tried CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP but it does not work.

I'm using `ShellExecuteEx` to launch the child EXE (it requires administrative privilege)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to launch the parent process without compatibility mode?

Comment: User is launching the parent process.

Comment: Ask them not to use compat mode is the easiest way. Will you program function without compat mode?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a task in Windows scheduler with your application and then run it.